# The required JS dependency "readable-stream/writable.js" is not available

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm trying to build my ClojureScript project. This error started popping up after updating Firebase. I'm using Node v13.11.0 and Yarn to manage NPM modules.

```
$ node -v
=> v13.11.0

$ shadow-cljs watch dashboard
[:dashboard] Build failure:

The required JS dependency "readable-stream/writable.js" is not available, it was required by "node_modules/stream-browserify/index.js".

Search in:
        /Users/petrus/Projects/some-project/node_modules
You probably need to run:
  npm install readable-stream/writable.js
```

Attempting to install it:

```
yarn add readable-stream/writable.js

error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/readable-stream/writable.js.git
Directory: /Users/petrus/Projects/bridge
Output:
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Also tried:

```
yarn add stream
yarn add readable-stream

yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
warning Pattern ["readable-stream@^3.6.0"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/Users/petrus/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/npm-readable-stream-3.6.0-337bbda3adc0706bd3e024426a286d4b4b2c9198-integrity/node_modules/readable-stream" as pattern ["readable-stream@^3.4.0","readable-stream@^3.4.0","readable-stream@2 || 3","readable-stream@^3.0.2","readable-stream@^3.1.1"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
```

So then I deleted `/Users/petrus/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/npm-readable-stream-3.6.0-337bbda3adc0706bd3e024426a286d4b4b2c9198-integrity/node_modules/readable-stream`, but I get the same error. Also tried `yarn cache clean`.

Can anyone help me get this thing installed?

Comment: What's the issue with `yarn add readable-stream`?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by fixing syntax error in ClojureScript source.

So this turned out to be an obscure error where I had a syntax error in my ClojureScript which did not fully compile, which seems to have resulted in Shadow-cljs not putting all the needed dependencies in the build target modules folder. Hence this error is unrelated to readable-stream.

Comment: what was the syntax error? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @KevinGlick I don't know, but I just ran into it again when I added firebase-admin to a Cljs project.